# Lefschetz fibration on product of surfaces

Tags: geometric-topology, symplectic-geometry, low-dimensional-topology, 4-manifolds

If I understand the literature correctly, then every symplectic 4 manifold (potentially up to connected sum with complex projective space) admits a lefschetz fibration with codomain a two sphere.

In particular there has to exist a lefschetz fibration (maybe up to blowup) from the product of two closed surfaces to the two sphere. What does such a map look like? What are the vanishing cycles and what is the fiber genus?